# Sorting through an array list of objects

Tags: java, csv, sorting, object, arraylist

I am trying to read data in from a CSV file containing 4 columns to an array list. Let's call the columns **a,b,c,d** (They each contain integers). Then I would like to sort the array list according to the contents of the rows of a,b,c,d.

So if you are comparing row 1 and 2 for example, if the value of *1d<2d* then return a certain value. If 1d=2d then compare 1c to 2c and so on. I am having trouble with finding a way to create an array list that allows me to differentiate and compare each row/column.

```
public class Speed {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        readCSV();
    }

    public static void readCSV() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("amis.csv"));
        String line = "";
        ArrayList<String> amis = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.replaceAll("\"", "");

            amis.add(line);
        }

        amis.remove(0);

        for (String alphabet: amis) {
            Object[] parts = alphabet.split(",");
            Object studentID = (parts[0]);
            Object a = parts[1];
            Object b = parts[2];
            Object c = (parts[3]);
            Object d = parts[4];
            ArrayList<Object> Compare = new ArrayList();

            Compare.add(a);
            Compare.sort(new customComparator());
        }
```

My custom comparator class

```
public class customComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        int a = (Integer) o1;
        int b = (Integer) o2;

        if (a < b) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(a > b)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing Strings to Objects with `Object[] parts = alphabet.split(",");`?  It looks like you later cast the Objects _(really Strings)_ as Integers, which surely gives a runtime error at the least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your current sorting method

```
for(String alphabet: amis)
{
    Object[] parts = alphabet.split(",");
    Object studentID = (parts[0]);
    Object a = parts[1];
    Object b = parts[2];
    Object c = (parts[3]);
    Object d = parts[4];
    ArrayList<Object> Compare = new ArrayList();

    Compare.add(a);
    Compare.sort(new customComparator());
}
```

The most blatant issue is you're creating an ArrayList, Compare, adding/sorting, then discarding it

If you're trying to make a second, sorted list:

```
List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(amis);
sorted.sort(new CustomComparator());
```

If you're just trying to sort the original list:

```
amis.sort(new CustomComparator());
```

---

You've gotten fairly close to what you want to do, by making a comparator, but it needs tweaking

Your current implementation stops after it checks the first value, it returns 0 instead of continuing

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    public int compare(String A, String B)
    {
        String[] as = A.split(",");
        String[] bs = B.split(",");

        int a = Integer.parseInt(a[4]); //column d, as an int
        int b = Integer.parseInt(b[4]);
        if(a < b)
            return 1;
        else
            if(a > b)
                return -1;
            else
            {
                a = Integer.parseInt(a[3]); //column c, as an int
                b = Integer.parseInt(b[3]);
                if(a < b)
                    return -1;
                else
                    if(a > b)
                        return 1;
                    else
                    {
                        a = Integer.parseInt(a[2]); //column b, as an int
                        b = Integer.parseInt(b[2]);
                        if(a < b)
                            return -1;
                        else
                            if(a > b)
                                return 1;
                            else
                            {
                                a = Integer.parseInt(a[1]); //column a, as an int
                                b = Integer.parseInt(b[1]);
                                if(a < b)
                                    return -1;
                                else
                                    if(a > b)
                                        return 1;
                                    else
                                        return 0; //all columns are the same
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Noticing that there is a lot of similar code, we can instead change it into a loop

```
public int compare(String A, String B)
{
    String[] as = A.split(",");
    String[] bs = B.split(",");

    for(int i = 4; i >= 1; i--) //columns d-a
    {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(b[i]);
        if(a < b)
            return -1;
        if(a > b)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer- it worked well. Just a quick question I don't understand how the String split method will allow the csv file to be divided into columns as opposed to rows.

Comment: @Abby When reading line by line, rows are being stored in the ArrayList, using split on each line in the ArrayList will give columns

Answer (score 0):

You should rather create POJO for each string and comparator for it. In the comparator you should compare more "important" columns first and go to less important if previous are equal.

```
public class Pojo {
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;
private int d;

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
}

public int getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(int c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public int getD() {
    return d;
}

public void setD(int d) {
    this.d = d;
}

public static class PojoComparator implements Comparator<Pojo> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Pojo pojo1, Pojo pojo2) {
        return pojo1==null ? (pojo2==null ? 0:1) :(pojo2==null?-1:
                (pojo1.d!=pojo2.d? pojo1.d-pojo2.d : 
                (pojo1.c!=pojo2.c ? pojo1.c-pojo2.c: 
                (pojo1.b!=pojo2.b? pojo1.b-pojo2.b:
                        pojo1.a-pojo2.a))) );
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: It's probably cleaner to just use public variables, instead of have public private ones